# Map to List error: Series object not callable

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary, nsepy

```
from nsepy import get_history
from datetime import date
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
file = r'C:\Users\Raspberry-Pi\Desktop\Desktop\List.xlsx'
list = pd.read_excel(file)
list = list['SYMBOL']
start = date.today()-datetime.timedelta(days = 10)
end = date.today()
symb = get_history(symbol='INFY',start = start,end = end)
h = symb.tail(3).High.tolist()
l = symb.tail(3).Low.tolist()
print(type(h))
print(type(l))
x =  map(lambda a,b:a-b,h,l)
print(type(x))
x = list(x)
```

I am getting error:

> series object not callable

and its pointing to `x = list(x)` line.

Comment: Can you put the entire error in the description

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But I think you can omit `map` and use simple subtract and then convert to `list`:

```
symb = get_history(symbol='INFY',start = start,end = end)
print ((symb.tail(3).High - symb.tail(3).Low).tolist())
```

Also don't use variable `list` (reserved word in python) rather  `L` (or something else):

```
L = pd.read_excel(file)
L = L['SYMBOL']
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

symb = pd.DataFrame({'High':[8,9,7,5,3,4],'Low':[1,2,3,1,0,1]})
print (symb)
   High  Low
0     8    1
1     9    2
2     7    3
3     5    1
4     3    0
5     4    1

print ((symb.tail(3).High - symb.tail(3).Low).tolist())
[4, 3, 3]
```

EDIT:

I try simulate problem:

```
list = pd.DataFrame({'SYMBOL':['sss old','dd','old']})
print (list)
     SYMBOL
0  sss old
1       dd
2      old

list = list['SYMBOL']
print (list)
0    sss old
1         dd
2        old
Name: SYMBOL, dtype: object

print (type(list))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

x = [1,2,3]

#list is Series, not function
x = list(x)
print (x)
TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable
```

---

If change `list` to `L`, is important reopen python console, because still same error.

So this works perfectly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'SYMBOL':['sss old','dd','old']})
print (df)
     SYMBOL
0  sss old
1       dd
2      old

L = df['SYMBOL']
print (L)
0    sss old
1         dd
2        old
Name: SYMBOL, dtype: object

x = [1,2,3]
x = list(x)
print (x)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 6):

`list(x)` normally means turn `x` into a `list` object.   It's a function that creates a list object.  But near the top you redefined `list`:

```
list = pd.read_excel(file)
```

Now `list` is now a pandas `series` object (as the error message says), and it does not function as a function, i.e. it is not `callable`, it cannot be used with `()`.

Use a different name for this object.  Use a silly name like `foo` if you can't think of a better descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have reassigned reserve word

```
list = pd.read_excel(file) 
list = list['SYMBOL']
```

hence list here is just a list of `['S', 'Y', 'M', 'B'..]`. Use another name for this definition the program will work fine

Comment: I test it and for me it works. Do you use python 2 or python 3?

Comment: I use python 2 and I am not a ardent programmer

Comment: Do you use pandas? Can you test it?

Comment: I do not use pandas

Comment: Because in pandas `list['SYMBOL']` means select column with name `SYMBOL` in `DataFrame` called `list`.

Comment: the problem is not with list['SYMBOL'], but with reassigning list = list['SYMBOL']. the reference to the function list() is lost and now list i simple plain list

Comment: Also if use [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) and not parameter `sheetname` you get `DataFrame`. And if use `list = list['SYMBOL']` you reassign `DataFrame` to `Series` (column called `SYMBOL`)

Comment: I add it to answer.